# Why does my dynamically added (back) jQuery handler fail?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I am replacing the html on a page when a button is clicked - everything, including the css and jQuery. The jQuery (button click event handler) works the first time, but not thereafter; in fact, it then throws an exception.

This static ajax jquery callback code contains this:

```
url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
      .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
      .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
      .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
```

...which gets transformed into this at runtime:

```
url: '/api/un/bd/ed'
      .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
      .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
      .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
```

This code is part of an ajax call in a button's event handler. As mentioned, it works perfectly the first time the button is clicked, but after the html (and css and jquery) is replaced in response to that click, I get the following:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
Requested URL      http://localhost:52194/@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = 
true, Abuelosit = "un", begdate = "2016-08-28", enddate = "2016-08-31" })?_=1473366761632
Physical Path      C:\Projects\ProActWebReports\ProActWebReports\@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: 
new { httpRoute = true, Abuelosit = "un", begdate = "2016-08-28", enddate = "2016-08-31" })

Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\cshannon\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\PROACTWEBREPORTS

More Information:
This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.
```

What resource has been removed? Which "file or directory does not exist on the server"? Actually, what looks very fishy in that exception message is this:

```
*Abuelosit = "un", begdate = "2016-08-28", enddate = "2016-08-31"*
```

It should be:

```
*unit = "Abuelos", begdate = "2016-08-28", enddate = "2016-08-31"*
```

...so it seems that "Abuelos" and "unit" are getting mangled/jumbled up somehow - *Abuelosit = "un"* should be *unit = "Abuelos"*. If this is the problem, how can I rectify it?

BTW, the REST method that is called (the first time the button is clicked) is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{unit}/{begdate}/{enddate}", Name = "QuadrantData")] 
public HttpResponseMessage GetQuadrantData(string unit, string begdate, 
    string enddate)
{
    _unit = unit;
    _beginDate = begdate;
    _endDate = enddate;
    string beginningHtml = GetBeginningHTML();
    string bodyBeginningHtml = GetBodyBeginHTML();
    string top10ItemsPurchasedHtml = GetTop10ItemsPurchasedHTML();
    string pricingExceptionsHtml = GetPricingExceptionsHTML();
    string forecastedSpendHtml = GetForecastedSpendHTML();
    string deliveryPerformanceHtml = GetDeliveryPerformanceHTML();
    string endingHtml = GetEndingHTML();
    String HtmlToDisplay = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}",
        beginningHtml,
        bodyBeginningHtml,
        top10ItemsPurchasedHtml,
        pricingExceptionsHtml,
        forecastedSpendHtml,
        deliveryPerformanceHtml,
        endingHtml);

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new StringContent(
            HtmlToDisplay,
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "text/html"
        )
    };
}
```

### UPDATE

For posterity, here is the old code (commented out) and the new, from Ricardo, that works:

First, in Index.cshtml (the raw html):

```
//$("#btnGetData").click(function () {
$("body").on( "click", "#btnGetData", function() {
```

And in the Controller code, where I'm dynamically generating html to replace the previous:

```
//builder.Append("$(\"#btnGetData\").click(function () {");
builder.Append("$(\"body\").on( \"click\", \"#btnGetData\", function() {");
```

This works perfectly now.

Comment: Look at your console: `Requested Url: http://localhost:52194/@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = ` obviously it's not doing what you think it is. *...which gets transformed into this at runtime:* isn't happening.

Comment: Right, I'm gettng "Abuelosit = "un"" which makes no sense; but if a transformation is not happening (if that's what you mean), how does it get changed from its state at design time?

Comment: to me it looks like whatever is supposed to convert `@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })` to `/api/un/bd/ed` isn't working.

Comment: I see nothing in your question related to a `back jquery handler` that's failing.

Comment: That is the entire point of the question - note its title. I don't know if I'd call it a "back jquery handler" though; it's one that has been added back.

Comment: but... there's no handler. Your problem is you have an ajax request that is throwing a 404 error. that has absolutely nothing to do with whatever event callback this ajax request might be in. The problem is simple: your url is wrong. fix it.

Comment: Sure there's a handler; it's the same exact code which works the first time, but not thereafter. The URL changes because somehow it's getting mangled, but my code is the same, so something else is going on here.

Comment: Right, "somehow it's getting mangled". how could that possibly happen? what are you doing to this code? how is it being created? where is it coming from? It appears as though it's not being parsed by the server before the client interprets it. thus re-enforcing that this has nothing to do with ajax or callbacks.

Comment: All that is stated; it is the exact same html; only the data in the tables differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if an AJAX request works fine the first time and fails the second time and you are replacing the original HTML with new HTML from the AJAX request, it means that the original click handlers are gone.

If you are attaching click handlers to the button like this:

```
$("button.someAction").click(function() {
    $.ajax("/api/a/b/c");
    // etc.
});
```

they will be gone once the AJAX request completes. When you click the button which no longer has an event handler it tries to submit something to the server and you get a weird URL.

You should be assigning them with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click()`. The `.on()` should be assigned to the container whose insides are replaced in the new request like this.

```
$("#container").on( "click", "button.someAction", function() {
  $.ajax("/api/a/b/c");
});
```

This way the action on the button will be maintained through all requests.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can "container" be "body" or "html"?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yes it can be body. What happens with `.on()` is that the click event on the button bubbles up through the DOM, gets caught by jQuery when it reaches `#container` (or whatever element you specify) and fires the event.

Comment: Awesome, I'll czech it out (probably not today) and if it works, award you the bounty.

Comment: What does what is represented as "button.someAction" need to actually be? My button has no explicitly specified "action". Can it just be the id of the button there ("#btnGetData")?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
url: '@Url.RouteUrl(routeName: "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = true, unit = "un", begdate = "bd", enddate = "ed" })'
      .replace("un", encodeURIComponent(_unit))
      .replace("bd", encodeURIComponent(_begdate))
      .replace("ed", encodeURIComponent(_enddate)),
```

The above code, the first time, is interpreted and correctly becomes the URL you expect.

**The second time it is treated as a string**.

And the URL contains that string, **not** your API url:

> ```
> Requested URL      http://localhost:52194/@Url.RouteUrl(routeName:
> "QuadrantData", routeValues: new { httpRoute = 
> true, Abuelosit = "un", begdate = "2016-08-28", 
> enddate = "2016-08-31" })?_=1473366761632
> ```

That's why "Unit=abuelos" becomes "abuelosit". Because you replace "un", and the word "unit" contains "un". So "unit" becomes "abuelosit" (just as "unique" would become "abuelosique").

You need to either parse your @variable **every time**, or save it somewhere and, just in case, I'd also recommend you use some more distinctive string:

```
var baseUrl = '@Url...unit="_Xx_un_xX_"...
```

Then you can copy baseUrl each time:

```
url = baseUrl.replace('_Xx_un_xX_', encodeURIComponent(_unit)...
```